# Using 'browser' object in vue / quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, cross-browser, quasar

I want to create an add bookmark button in my website so that users can easily bookmark my page for future reference. So, I googled a bit and found a clean way which is using the [browser.bookmarks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks/create)

I am currently using vue (options API) for my website.
Here is my code snippet for that -

```
methods: {
   addBookmark() {
     const bookmark = {title: 'My Book', url: 'www.bookkay.com'}
     browser.bookmarks.create(bookmark)
  }
}
```

However, I am getting error that browser object is not defined.
[image: Console Output of Error]

I believe this is because browser object is not available in the scope of vue methods.

So, pls feel free to share some workarounds for this problem. Either trying to get the browser object available in vue components methods scope or an alternative way to create bookmarks using javascript.

Comment: `browser.bookmarks` is for web extensions API - are you writing a web extension? personally, if I went to a a website that could `create bookmarks using javascript`, I'd block it forever and tell the world about the crap that it does :p bookmarks are a users choice, not for some website to manipulate

Comment: Thanks @Bravo for your reply. I didn't knew the browser.bookmarks API was a web extension api. I am writing a SPA so, i cannot use that. And you made a good point there that you would never use a website that automatically bookmark itself without user's consent. But I really wish there is some sort of API that will ask the permission from the user like when opening the webcam, and with user's permission add the bookmark.